# DT sorting problem - custom number formating

Tags: r, datatables, dt

I try to sort numbers by variables in DT::datatable() when user click to sort button.

I have date like this (B: Billion, M: Million)

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 B | 3 B | 3 B |
| 99 B | 2 M | 4 M |
| 3 M | 3 B | 1 B |
| 99 B | 2 M | 2 M |

I want to sort by special characters B and M. I tried to use format functions in DT but I couldn't fix it.

Any ideas?

The data:

```
structure(list(Value = c(3.549e+09, 2.95e+09, 3.005e+09, 3.744e+09, 
4.676e+09, 4.882e+09, 4.188e+09, 2.613e+09, 1.37e+09, 1.204e+09, 
1.428e+09, 3.845e+09, 6.251e+09, 6.815e+09, 2.782e+09), CValue = c(3.549e+09, 
-5.99e+08, 5.5e+07, 7.39e+08, 4.676e+09, 2.06e+08, -6.94e+08, 
-1.575e+09, 1.37e+09, -1.66e+08, 2.24e+08, 2.417e+09, 6.251e+09, 
5.64e+08, -4.033e+09)), row.names = 3458:3472, class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Codes:

```
    library(DT)
    datatable(data)
```

Comment: You can first convert them into real numbers (without "B" or "M") then you can sort them by quantity with `dplyr::arrange`.

Comment: I want to sort them in DT::datatable() when they click to sort button by variables in html file.

Comment: Could you post an expected output? And could you also provide the data with `dput()` ([see description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/12242625)).

Comment: Output have a datatable, originally the datatable put sort buttons on the table. But when convert the numbers to character it's only sort by first character in instances. I want to sort them by number and special character, for example, the column like this: 1 B, 3 M, 2 B, 99 B and when the user click sort button it should be sorted  like 1 M, 3 M, 99 M,  1 B, 2 B or descending  order.

Comment: Are there only B and M in the table ?

Comment: No there is also K and T but your answer is very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can achieve what you wat with the `render` option:

```
library(DT)

dat <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("2 B", "13 M", "5.5 M"),
  V2 = c("99 M", "4 B", "1 B")
)

js <- c(
  "function(data, type, row, meta){",
  "  if(type === 'sort' || type === 'type'){",
  "    var factors = {M: 1e6, B: 1e9};",
  "    var split = data.split(' ');",
  "    var number = Number(split[0]);",
  "    var unit = split[1];",
  "    data = number * factors[unit];",
  "  }",
  "  return data;",
  "}"
)

datatable(
  dat,
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(
        targets = c(1, 2), render = JS(js)
      )
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: It's working well thank you :)